# Recursive function doesn't print list

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to understand recursion, and I made small piece of code to check my understanding. Unfortunately, my function doesn't print any element of list.

```
list=['zero','one','two','three',0,1,2,3]

def rekur(list):
    for element in list:
        if isinstance(element,int):
            rekur(list)
        else:
            print(element)
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never called the function.  You need one more line:

```
# Function

def rekur(list):
    for element in list:
        if isinstance(element,int):
            rekur(list)
        else:
            print(element)

# Main program

list=['zero','one','two','three',0,1,2,3]
rekur(list)
```

**WARNING**: You have an infinite recursion.  As soon as you reach an integer, you recur on the entire list, in its original form.  I'm not sure what purpose you have, that makes an integer a case for recursion, so I don't know how to fix this for you.  The current program emits

```
zero
one
two
three
zero
one
two
three
zero
...
```

until it overflows the call stack.

Comment: Interesting. I`ll try to figure out how to stop this. Its only excercise function and I randomly choose ints to print.

Comment: The problem is that when you hit an int, you simply repeat your original call, starting again from the front.  Perhaps you'd be interested in `rekur(list[:element])`, which recurs on only the first `elements` items in the list.